PHP PDO error "Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause"
I am trying to use the pdo_mysql PHP extension with emulation of prepared statements disabled.
The code is equivalent to the following:
$db_connection = new PDO(
    $prefix . ':dbname=' . $DatabaseName . ';host=' . $DatabaseServer . ';port=' . $DatabasePort . ';charset=utf8mb4',
    $DatabaseUsername,
    $DatabasePassword,
    [
        // @link https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_UPPER,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => true,
    ]
);

$sql = "SELECT AVG(CUM_WEIGHTED_GPA) AS CUM_WEIGHTED_GPA,
    AVG(UNWEIGHTED_GPA) AS CUM_UNWEIGHTED_GPA
    FROM transcript_grades
    WHERE SYEAR='2023'
    AND SCHOOL_ID='1'
    AND MARKING_PERIOD_ID='4'";

$stmt = $db_connection->query( $sql );

if ( $stmt )
{
    $stmt->execute();

    var_dump( $stmt->errorInfo() );
}

The following error is returned:
42000 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Here are the SQL modes set in MariaDB 10.11.6:
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

The same query is fine when PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true.
Please note, the SQL query is not a prepared statement.

Not sure that this question belongs here; the problem appears to be caused by the driver.

mariadb will not show that error with code

see if you can reproduce your problem https://dbfiddle.uk/RfhzBXAC

@nbk thanks for the fiddle. The transcript_grades is actually a VIEW depending on 4 other tables. https://gitlab.com/francoisjacquet/rosariosis/-/blob/mobile/rosariosis_mysql.sql#L2065 That being said, I have run the query in the MariaBD console, and it runs fine.

Bug reported at https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/15386

The PDO::query() function both prepares and executes an SQL statement.
So there is no need to call the PDOStatement::execute() function, and the following line should be removed from the code in the question above:
$stmt->execute();

